# C/C++ and C# syntax checker that could be run over a list of files

Tags: c#, c++, c, syntax-error

Could you please recommend me C/C++ and C# syntax checker, that could be run from a command line. I have got about 12000 files written in C/C++ and C#, about 1000 of them are with errors, so I need to find out that bunch of files to correct them manually.

Comment: Why not just use the compiler? As a syntax checker won't check for references and various other things. So it won't be 100% accurate

Comment: It's Microsoft C/C++. There is no way to compile them - the whole compilation process takes a day...

Comment: Would removing the linking step cut down build time enough that you could run it through the Microsoft tools?  Using some other syntax checker could still leave many bugs in your code if you are targeting the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: @zvoice: It takes a day to compile them... why do you care?  It will take you a day to respond to any syntax errors detected.  Can the entire set change faster than once a day? How?

Comment: If the files are so bad that there are a thousand _syntax_ errors, how many other errors are there? Those will take far more of your time. A single memory corruption bug can easily cost a week on projects this size.

Answer (score 3):

For C and C++ you can use `gcc` and `g++` with the `-fsyntax-only` [flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options). However, as has been said in the comments, this won't find undefined references and other link time errors.

Microsoft's C/C++ compiler has a similar [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we9a1ahs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). I am not sure if it works with C# as well though.

Comment: It's Microsoft C/C++. There is no way to compile them - the whole compilation process takes a day...

Comment: It seems Microsoft's C/C++ compiler has a similar option. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The technically best way to do this is to simply compile each file.  Setting up all those compiles is either easy (because you have the build scripts) or will be h--- if you don't have them, and the difference may drive your choice of solution.

For C, you pretty much need to run them through a compiler with the preprocessor enabled. If you don't do that, the typical C code containg macros and preprocessor conditionals won't be parsable at all.

Likewise for C++, although people tend to use the preprocessor less. You might get away with a C++ source file parser, but any syntax errors produced would have to checked to see if they were caused by preproessor directives or macros.   If you want to avoid setting up the compile scripts, our [C++ Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CppFormatter.html) can be configured to process the code without running the preprocessor, so it might be useful here. It really parses the file, and then prettyprints it; you can just ignore the prettyprint part and check if the exit status on a file is "OK" (no errors) or "not OK" (some kind of syntax/semantic error).

C# does have a preprocessor but it is used only sparingly.  You can find a similar C# formatter from us in our [family of formatters for many languages](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters).  The family handles not only a specific language, but usually several of the more common dialects (GCC, MS, ...)

Comment: Hello, Ira. Setting compilers like these wouldn't be a better solution. I have got a remote VM with very poor connection to test my code on it, here I have no opportunity to run all the scripts, building this source. So I need a tool like ... hm..  Understand, but which would give me only syntax errors (using only grammar parser, without any compilation). Errors in the code are very-very simple, so there is no need to do any of preprocessing either.

Comment: @zvoice: "no need to do any preprocessing"  To check syntax on C programs, as a practical matter you don't have a choice; I don't understand how this isn't obvious to you. (If it isn't, pick a random C program and feed it to our C Formatter)  Regarding "compilers like these" ... I'm not sure what you are referring to.  If you mean the formatters I mention, those formatters ARE NOT compilers; but they do PARSE using a full grammar and will report syntax errors. "Understand (the product)" seems like a sledgehammer for your problem, and won't avoid the preprocessing issue at all.

Comment: These tools are commercial software.  Check prices at website.